# Is there a limit to virtual console TTY's in Linux Based OS'es

Tags: linux, terminal, tty

The TeleType Consoles in linux can be switched by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F(#TTY)</kbd>.

How many such TTY's can linux have at a time? Is there even a limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only run a virtual console (VC) on a tty device that exists.  By default, Debian Linux ships with 64 such device files (**/dev/tty0** through **/dev/tty63**).  Other reading suggests that the limit in the kernel by default is 256 of these, so it may be possible to create up to **/dev/tty255**. If you need more than that, you'll probably have to recompile the kernel.

The more practical limitation, however, is how do you actually *use* that many VCs?  <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> will only get you up to VC 12 on most keyboards (10 on others).  To extend this number, most Linux systems ship with <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> mapped to VCs 13 through 24.  Beyond this, you can do your own keyboard mapping, which you can read about [here](http://codeidol.com/unix/linux-desktop/Console/Redefine-Keyboard-Actions/) if this is something you're interested in doing.

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> to cycle through all VTs. And the `chvt` command can be used to directly change to any active VT.

Comment: @Rinzwind of Askubuntu is saying that your answer is wrong.Please verifiy http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1316873#1316873

Comment: Wrong in what regard?

Comment: `Alt`+`Left`, `Alt`+`Right`, `chvt` can be used to access all available VCs.

Comment: @grawity: good call, I forgot about that. I'll update my answer.